# Google Analytics custom dimensions not working

Tags: javascript, json, gtag.js

So i'm trying to edit the google tag to track my logged in users. The view is ready with user-id tracking in Analytics, but i can't seem to get the code to work.

This is as far as i'v gotten

```
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-5769176-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
    
  gtag('config', 'UA-5769176-1',{
        'custom_map':{'dimension1': 'Logged in'}
    });
    gtag('event','page_view',{'Logged in':'subscriber'});
</script>
```

There is a custom dimension named 'Logged in' created in Google analytics. My guess is the next part is where things go wrong.

Any help would be apreciated.

```
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-5769176-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
    
  gtag('config', 'UA-5769176-1',{
        'custom_map':{'dimension1': 'Logged in'}
    });
    gtag('event','page_view',{'Logged in':'subscriber'});
</script>
```

I expected to see the activity of my logged in users, and only my logged in users, inside my Google analytics view.